# Making a line break in the table header breaks tabularray?

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabularray

As the title suggests, I'm trying to achieve a linebreak in the first table between Endkonzentration \\ N-Acetylcystein but it ends up making the table look weird, giving me a LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item twice over. Now the second table is almost the same, with the exception of `colspec = X[c, si={table-format=xyz}]`, which seems to fix the issue. Is there a way to get this to work without the siunitx formulation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
    \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}
    \SetTblrStyle{headsep}{}

    \SetTblrStyle{foot}{font=\footnotesize}

\DefTblrTemplate{remark-sep}{three}{:\space}
\DefTblrTemplate{note-sep}{three}{\,}   

\DefTblrTemplate{remark}{inline-noclosingpar}{% similar to the remark plain 
\MapTblrRemarks{%
    \noindent%
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark-tag}{default}%
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark-sep}{three}%
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark-text}{default}% 
    \space\space}
}

    
\DefTblrTemplate{note}{inline-three}{%
    \MapTblrNotes{%
        \noindent%
        \UseTblrTemplate{note-tag}{default}%
        \UseTblrTemplate{note-sep}{three}%
        \UseTblrTemplate{note-text}{default}%
        \space}
}

\DefTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytemplate}{%
    \UseTblrTemplate{remark}{inline-noclosingpar}%
    \UseTblrTemplate{note}{inline-three}%
}
\NewTblrTheme{mytheme}{%
    \SetTblrTemplate{lastfoot}{mytemplate}%
}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{talltblr}[
  theme=mytheme,
  caption = {Pipettierschema der Ausgleichgerade},%
  label = {tab:ps1},%
  remark{Hinweis} = {Volumenangaben in \textmu L}.,%
  remark{Quelle} = {\cite{bib:skript}}.\\,%
  note{a} = in \textmu M.,%
  %note{b} = Verdünnung 1:10.,
]{colspec = {
                        %@{}
                        c c c c
                        @{}
                        },
             row{1}  = {
             guard, 
             m, 
             cmd=\hskip0pt}
            }
\toprule
         {Endkonzentration\\N-Acetylcystein}\TblrNote{a} & {V\textsubscript{PBS}} & {V\textsubscript{Acetylcystein-Lösung}}
         & {V\textsubscript{DTNB-Stammlösung}}\\ 
         \midrule
          0 & 1000 & 0 & 50 \\
          5 & 995 & 5 & 50 \\
          10 & 990 & 10 & 50 \\
          15 & 985 & 15 & 50 \\
          20 & 980 & 20 & 50 \\
          25 & 975 & 25 & 50 \\
          30 & 970 & 30 & 50 \\
          \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{talltblr}[
  theme=mytheme,
  caption = {Pipettierschema Teilversuch 2},%
  label = {tab:ps2},%
  note{a} = {[mM]},%
  note{b} = {(5 mM)},%
  note{c} = {(1 M)},%
  note{d} = {(12 mM)},%
  note{e} = {(1,0 \textmu g/ml)},%
  remark{Hinweis} = {Angaben mit Ausnahme der Pyruvatkonzentration in \textmu l.},%
  remark{Quelle} = {\cite{bib:skript}.\\},%
]{colspec = {
                      %  @{}
                            c X[c, si={table-format=0.3}]
                              X[c, si={table-format=3.0}]
                         *{4}{X[c, si={table-format=2.0}]}
                        % *{2}{X[c, si={table-format=1.0}]}
                        @{}
                        },
             row{1}  = {guard, m, cmd=\hskip0pt} 
            }
    \toprule
{nº}  & {Pyruvat-\\konzen-\\tration}\TblrNote{a}
            & {Bidestilliertes Wasser}
                    & {Pyruvat}\TblrNote{b}   
                    & {Imidazol-\\puffer}\TblrNote{c}   
                                        & {NADH}\TblrNote{d}    & {LDH-\\lösung}\TblrNote{e}\\
    \midrule
        1 & 0,01 & 878 & 2 & 50 & 20 & 50 \\ 
        2 & 0,015 & 877 & 3 & 50 & 20 & 50 \\ 
        3 & 0,02 & 876 & 4 & 50 & 20 & 50 \\ 
        4 & 0,03 & 874 & 6 & 50 & 20 & 50 \\ 
        5 & 0,05 & 870 & 10 & 50 & 20 & 50 \\ 
        6 & 0,075 & 865 & 15 & 50 & 20 & 50 \\ 
        7 & 0,1 & 860 & 20 & 50 & 20 & 50 \\ 
        8 & 0,15 & 850 & 30 & 50 & 20 & 50 \\ 
        9 & 0,2 & 840 & 40 & 50 & 20 & 50 \\ 
        10 & 0,25 & 830 & 50 & 50 & 20 & 50 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Tables]

Answer (score 2):

`{Endkonzentration\\N-Acetylcystein\TblrNote{a}}` not `{Endkonzentration\\N-Acetylcystein}\TblrNote{a}`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{talltblr}{}
% {Endkonzentration\\N-Acetylcystein}\TblrNote{a} &
{Endkonzentration\\N-Acetylcystein\TblrNote{a}} &
{V\textsubscript{PBS}} &
{V\textsubscript{Acetylcystein-Lösung}} &
{V\textsubscript{DTNB-Stammlösung}}\\
\end{talltblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]